# Oracle APEX 5.0 Classic Report window.print() issue

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I created a classic report in oracle apex 5.0 which has a few product info (colour, szie, price etc.) as well as a Barcode column. To display the barcode column in a specific barcode font, I uploaded a piece of jquery code as plugin and managed to get the barcode displayed correctly like below
[image]

But when it comes to printing, the print function that comes with APEX doesn't work, because it only prints out the original barcode value (6208217iFiEiGi1i) which is returned by the sql. As a workaround, I created a button that calls a javascript which does window.print(), and used some CSS to get rid of the header and the sidebar of the web page, and managed to only print the main content of the web page which is the report.

The way I did is, I have the below CSS code in the html header of my page

```
<style media="print" type="text/css">
@media print
{
body * { visibility: hidden; }
#print-content * { visibility: visible; }
#print-content { position: relative; top: 0; left: 0; width:100%;  padding:0; }      
}
</style>
```

and the below in the region header and footer section I want to print

```
<div id="print-content" >

</div>
```

However, this approach left me with another issue. Sometimes the row gets cut off at the end of the page, that makes it look like below
[image]

Can anyone give me some suggestions on how I get around with this issue?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Try using this CSS - I'm not sure what you should apply it to, perhaps table rows in general:

```
@media print {
    tr {page-break-inside: avoid;}
}
```

Possibly a more specific selector would be preferable like `div#myreport tr`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I managed to get it working by add the below line into my CSS    
    #print-content *{ page-break-inside:avoid; }